# Support settings 2 languages in one travis ci file (objective-c and node for react-native)

Tags: objective-c, node.js, xcode, react-native, travis-ci

I tried to run XCUITest (Objective-C/swift) on travis ci for a react-native project while there's also node jest unit tests that I'll be running. I was wondering what the best way is to set up the `travis.yml` file since XCUITest is in Objective-C and jest unit tests are in node_js. I've done some research but not sure what a good way to do it is.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the travis.yml file can be set up this way

```
language: objective-c

git:
  submodules: false

sudo: required
services:
  - docker

node_js:
  - "5.10.1"

before_install:
  - npm install

env:
  - export NODE_VERSION="5.10.1"

script:
  - npm test
  - cd ios/ && xcodebuild test ...
```

hopefully it's useful to some people